# Can I declare a Composite-Component using only xhtml file and still be able to use the component in a JAVA code

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I am trying to create a composite-component using jsf simple tags without taking the advantages of UIComponent. I mean I do not want to implement the component by inheriting from UIComponentBase,UIComponentBase,etc. However, after the implementation, I want to be able to use the component in JAVA code. For example, consider the composite component below(lets call it MYcompositeComponent):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
    //...
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
        <composite:interface>
            <composite:attribute name="anything" />
        </composite:interface>
        <composite:implementation>
            #{cc.attrs.anything}
        </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Then I want to use this component in a JAVA class as below:

```
public class JavaClass {
    private MYcompositeComponent mYcompositeComponent;
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been similar answers to that question. [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) has a utility method called `Components.includeCompositeComponent(UIComponent parent, String libraryName, String resourceName, String id)` which will add your component to another `UIComponent` programmatically. This will return the composite component and

> ... which can if necessary be further used to set custom attributes or value expressions on it.